# Dynamic table (colons depend on the content of the table)

Tags: php, html, html-table, dynamic-tables

This php code shows me the content of a directory on my website:

```
<?php
 $dir = opendir(getcwd());
 ?>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<?php
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
      {
            echo "<td>". $file ."</td>";
    }       
  }
  closedir($dir);
?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

It puts the results in a `table`.
The problem is that the PHP code generates a `<td>` tag and store the results in it. So the final `table` has one `<tr>` and as many `<td>` tags as there are results.

What I want to have is a `table` with 3 columns (3 td) per each line (tr tag).

Is there a way to make the table dynamic and for each third `<td>` tag turns to be a `<tr>` tag
so the results look like this: [(click here)](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/logs/the%20wanted%20result.html)

Instead of looking like this: [(click here)](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/logs/test.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
 $dir = opendir(getcwd());
 ?>
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>

<?php
  $n = 0;
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
      {
           if($n%3 == 0){echo "<tr>";}
           echo "<td>". $file ."</td>";
           $n++;
    }       
  }
  closedir($dir);
?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: this will not work. When the first loop runs, a <tr>, 1 <td> with filename will be written out and already 1 closing </tr>. So no three columns.

Comment: cool! I'm not sure about this new setup though. $n will always be $n, and since your check for writing out the start <tr> is different from the check for writing out the end </tr>, there's theoretically a possibility that a table row is never closed.
I always use the setup described in my answer, never fails me...

Comment: thank you so much it worked 
the exact code you gave me ..
i've seen the source code of the result
and there's no end tag like this </tr>
but the browsers close the <tr> automatically .. in html
and all the other opened tags .. (i've read that before)
thank you any way sir

Comment: most browsers will render the table fine even though a closing <tr> is missing, but it is still not valid XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to keep track of where you are in the loop.
Then, when you've hit a multiplication of 3, you restart the table row:

```
<?php
   $dir = opendir(getcwd());
?>
<body>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <?php
                $counter = 0;
                while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
                    {
                        if($counter % 3 == 0 && $counter != 0) echo "</tr><tr>";
                        echo "<td>". $file ."</td>";
                        $counter++;
                    }       
                }
                closedir($dir);
            ?>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: i think your code is pretty much the same as the previous answer
you put another variable $counter in staid of $n
but your code needs two things if you want it to work : the first is to add {} 
like this if($counter % 3 == 0 && $counter != 0) {echo "</tr><tr>";}
the second is to add
$counter++; for increment
but thank you sir for your answer

Comment: you're right about the increment, I've added it.
And for a single if statement like this, you don't need those curly brackets.