# display the content of a folder

Tags: php, ftp

I have the following PHP code to display the content of a directory in my website:

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect("host") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");

if ($_GET['dir'] != null) {
    ftp_chdir($conn, "logs/{$_GET['dir']}");
}
else
{
    ftp_chdir($conn, "logs");
}

$files = ftp_nlist($conn,"");

foreach($files as $value) {
    echo "<a href=\"test.php?dir={$value}\">{$value}</a>";
}

ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

[This is my webpage](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)

When I click on the subdirectory1 or subdirectory2, I get the content of it (some images).  Then when I click on one of the images, I get the content of the root directory of my website.

How can I display only the image when a visitor clicks on it?  Note that I don't want to download it or anything  - I just want to display it in the browser when a visitor clicks on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish which of the returned items are files and which are directories. For that you are better of using [ftp_rawlist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) as it allows to extract more data. Then create links for each case and so you can process them appropriately. Here's a possible implementation:

```
$ftpHost = 'hostname';
$ftpUser = 'username';
$ftpPass = 'password';
$startDir = 'logs';

if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
    // Get file contents (can also be fetched with cURL)
    $contents = file_get_contents("ftp://$ftpUser:$ftpPass@$ftpHost/$startDir/" . urldecode($_GET['file']));

    // Get mime type (requires PHP 5.3+)
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $mimeType = $finfo->buffer($contents);

    // Set content type header and output file
    header("Content-type: $mimeType");
    echo $contents;
}
else {
    $dir = (isset($_GET['dir'])) ? $_GET['dir'] : '';

    $conn = ftp_connect($ftpHost) or die("Could not connect");
    ftp_login($conn, $ftpUser, $ftpPass);

    // change dir to avoid ftp_rawlist bug for directory names with spaces in them
    ftp_chdir($conn, "$startDir/$dir");

    // fetch the raw list
    $list = ftp_rawlist($conn, '');

    foreach ($list as $item) {
        if(!empty($item)) {
            // Split raw result into pieces
            $pieces = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $item, 9);

            // Get item name
            $name = $pieces[8];

            // Skip parent and current dots
            if ($name == '.' || $name == '..')
                continue;

            // Is directory
            if ($pieces[0]{0} == 'd') {
                echo "<a href='?dir={$dir}/{$name}'><strong>{$name}</strong></a><br />";
            }
            // Is file
            else {
                echo "<a href='?file={$dir}/{$name}'>{$name}</a><br />";
            }
        }
    }

    ftp_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: i got the content of the directory "logs" + the content of all the subdirectories in the same page ! [link to my page](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)

Comment: I've just tested the code from my answer and it works just fine for me (albeit the ftp server I'm testing with is on a Windows machine). Did you copy/paste the code from the answer or made some changes to it?

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($list);` so I can see the structure it's fetching?

Comment: can you give me your e-mail please ? i will contact you with my ftp informations login and all .. and you tell me what's wrong ?
my website is on trial version .. i just started building it 
it's a free ftp account .. not paid host lol (6te.net)

Comment: Firstly, I'm not making my email public here. Secondly, you're asking me to do the work for you. You should look over the code I provided you, try to understand it and if there are things you don't understand ask me to explain them or give references for you to read (which I will be more than happy to do). Or in this case just post the info I ask for (if possible), so I can help you further. I can understand if you are a beginner, but you need to understand how things work to get better. Asking users it this community to do the work for you will not get you very far.

Comment: ok i added `var_dump($list)` to the code you gift me
and this is the result [link to my page](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)

Comment: I've updated the answer taking into account the `var_dump` you provided. More exactly I've removed the `ftp_rawlist` last parameter set to `true` which was fetching a recursive list of the child directories and files (the `$recursive` parameter specified in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php)). Also added a check for parent and current directory listing results `$name != '.' && $name != '..'` (you can read more about that here http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/num/dotdot.htm). Let me know if that fixes the issue

Comment: i still can see the parent directory '.' && '..'
and once i click on a folder i can't see its content
[this is the link to my page](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/test.php)
click on subdirectory1 
it has 3 pictures inside !
but i can't see them, no files list no nothing

Comment: so basically your code works fine and can make difrences between a folder and a file ! and can display a file in the navigator (like index.html that i have there)
but once i click on a folder i can't see it's content
so the changes must be made in this area : if the item is a folder (the code to be excuted must be changed)

Comment: Have you even tried to figure out on your own why it's only partially working? I'm trying to be as benevolent as possible here, but you're making it really hard. Read this article http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: am sorry i really try to solve my issue here ! you don't know how much !

Comment: I've updated the answer again. This time it will work 100% since I created a test account myself on the hosting service you mentioned to test the script there: http://souser.6te.net. There is a bug with the `ftp_rawlist` function that returns an empty result if the directory name contain spaces (and the ones you were testing on did contain spaces).

Comment: no ! my directories didn't have any space in its names
but yours contain spaces (directory with images)
i tested it ! and it worked ! you're a god !
if i had a sister i would marry her to you ! god ! thank you so much
and a big thanks for the pages you gift me
i will read tutorials and read more about programing in staid of asking people thank you for all what you did to me

Comment: Glad to be of help. If that did the trick for you, then accept the answer so that anyone coming across this post can see it's a valid solution to your question.

Comment: Also just to make sure you did not misunderstand me. There's nothing wrong with asking questions, just do some research before you ask, so you can have a better understanding of the problem when you ask the question. That will help you get better, and a better explanation of the problem will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: i got one more issue i have added this to your code $n = 0; if($n%3 == 0){echo "<tr>";} $n++;` because i putted the results in a table and i wanted to creat a new <tr> tag for each 3 results so they appear good but it didn't work [see here](http://ahstpc.6te.net/site/1.php)
i have used this because i already putted a question [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799053/dynamic-table-colons-depend-on-the-content-of-the-table) to find out how to make the table look in order
but i couldn't combine the 2 codes  (the one you gift me and the one i got in that answer)

Comment: i was trying to make it work for half of a day but i didn't make it
i don't want you to update your answer this time ! 
i want to learn ! please JUST tell me what's wrong or where the mistake is located 
so i can correct it myself !
because i was trying to correct it the whole day and i couldn't find it

Comment: i actually tried to change your code (line 55)
and i putted the function `while (list(, $item) = each($list))`
in staid of the function `foreach ($list as $item)`
and it gives the same result and i think it's similar !
but i prefer to work with 'while' in staid of 'foreah'
so i can add the condition `if($n%3 == 0){echo "<tr>";}`
i believe that i did 50% of the job
now i want to know where to put `if($n%3 == 0){echo "<tr>";}`

Comment: You need to be carefull using [each](http://www.php.net/each) because it changes the internal pointer of the array on each iteration. So if you want to use it, you should call `reset($list)` before the `while` statement to reset the pointer to the first position ([reset() Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)). About the table row condition you should echo the new `<tr>` before you output any `<td>` element, which it this case should be before this line `if ($pieces[0]{0} == 'd') {`. Make sure you increment your `$n` counter (`$n++`) after the if statement;

Comment: i want please to specify if a folder is empty
the condition should be `if(unset($name))` right?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a function which checks which type of file we're handling.
If it's a directory show the regular link (the one you're using now) and if it's an image
show a link with the path of the image.

Because `$value` contains the name of the file you can use `end(explode('.',$value));` to find the ext. of the file (php , jpg , gif , png).
Use another condition with the piece of information and you can identify if it's a picture or not.

In order to build the `path` of the image you'll need to use the `$_GET['dir']` variable's value.
For instance:

```
<a href='<?=$_GET['dir']?>/Flower.gif'>Flower.gif</a>
```

I hope you got the idea.